# How Reset Unity Animator And Animation Clip?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, animator

I'm working on 2D game in unity and the game has several animation clip like : Idle, Idle Stomach, Figure and etc.
Also I have two section in my scene: 1- home 2-character

My default animation is "Idle" and I use SetTrigger to run the specific animation clip.
Animation and trigger work fine but when I trigger from "Idle" to another animation like "Figure" and switch between home and character (character section false -> home section true -> home section false, character section true) , my Idle animation blend with another clip witch it has trigger before and it has some frame from figure or stomach animation.

[image]

How can I reset animator like when scene load? or reset Idle clip for example?

I try these separately :

1. true/false animator component
2. set trigger Idle animation again
3. use Play("normalState", 0, 0f);

but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the exit node in the animator, doing this will automatically make the animator go the default animation clip.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XigM7.png

Add this to layer 0 and use Play("Exit", 0);

Comment: Hi, thank for reply, but my problem isn't go the default animation, it's my Idel animation after disable/enable character section blend with last animation

Comment: I want run animator just like when scene load first time.

Comment: i have a couple questions: 1) are you using resetTrigger()? 2) when you say blend do you mean it goes back and forth or you using a blend tree? 3)is this happening because you're loading multiple scenes or is this happening with no scene loading?

Comment: Nop,1- I'm not using ResetTrigger() , actually it not useful for my issue. 2- I'm not using blend tree, I mean Idle Animation frame(My first animation) blend with other animation. 3- if I use separately scene I haven't issue. but I use One scene for my sections.

Comment: It seems like because you're not using ResetTrigger(), it won't cancel the animations that were triggered before, and ResetTrigger() would keep those triggered animations from running again. Because from what i understand you are triggering animation Idle, then triggering animation figure, but it instead goes back and forth between idle and figure quickly right?